# Phone is off / black when I plug it into charger, only the Apple logo is displayed

Tags: iphone, contacts, charging

My small nephew dropped my iPhone 4s. There is a small crack on the screen. Now the iPhone is off / black and when I plug it into a charger only the Apple logo is displayed.

How can I retrieve my photos & contact list from the mobile? Is it not repairable?

Comment: Have you tried turning it on? Does your computer recognise the iPhone?

Comment: Yeah, i tried it but it did not worked...same the apple logo is displayed is on & off only.

Comment: So, your computer doesn't recognise iPhone when it's on (connected via USB)?

Comment: Yes... :(  How can i retrieve my photos & contact list?? I had not connect it to i-cloud too :(

Comment: If it won't boot & you have no backup, then your only hope is that a repairer can fix it without needing to restore it. Otherwise, your data's gone.

Answer (score 2):

Give [TinyUmbrella](http://tinyumbrella.org/fix-recovery/) a try. It's a powerful tool to exit the recovery state of the iPhone without the data loss.

1. Make sure that your iPhone is on (showing the Apple logo in your case)
2. Connect your iPhone to your computer via USB
3. Download and install TinyUmbrella
4. Launch TinyUmbrella and wait until it recognises your iPhone
5. As iPhone gets recognised press `exit recovery` shown in the main menu

[image: TinyUmbrella screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you can solve these problems by putting the phone into recovery mode and restoring it from backup. To do that, follow these instructions:

1. Connect the iPhone's USB cable to your computer, but not your iPhone.
2. Turn your iPhone off. If the phone won't turn off in the traditional manner, just keep holding the buttons until the screen goes dark.
3. Once you've turned the device off, press the home button on the face of the device and plug in the USB cable to the device's dock connector.
4. When it turns on, keep pressing the home button until the iTunes logo appears on the screen.
5. You'll know the phone is now in recovery mode because a window in iTunes will tell you.
6. You can then start the restore process by clicking the "Restore" button in the iTunes window.

If this still doesn't work, then you can use commercial software such as Dr.Fone to fix this kind of issues. A simple tutorial can be found out in [here](http://www.mobiledic.com/ios-topics/fix-iphone-stuck-on-apple-logo.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your screen is black or frozen, you might need to force restart your device. A force restart won't erase the content on your device. You can force restart your device even if the screen is black or the buttons aren't responding. Follow these steps:

iPad models with Face ID: Press and quickly release the Volume Up [button](https://smartservicingcentre.co.uk). Press and quickly release the Volume Down button. Then press and hold the Power button until the device restarts.

Answer (score -1):

Use a suitable way to restart iPhone is a good idea, refer to the [Apple website](https://support.apple.com/HT201559).

**Restart iPhone X or update model:**
Press and hold the side button and any volume buttons until the slider appears.
Drag the slider to completely turn off the device. 
After turning off the device, press the side button again until you see the Apple logo.

**Restart iPhone 8 or earlier, iPad or iPod touch:**
Press and hold the top (or side) button until the slider appears.
Drag the slider to completely turn off the device.
Once the device is turned off, press and hold the top (or side) button again until you see the Apple logo.

If the restart and recovery mode does not solve your problem, this [article](https://www.fonecope.com/fix-iphone-stuck-on-apple-logo-screen.html) may give you some help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will help preserve your answer for other users who may benefit in future.

Comment: @user97627 Thanks for the heads up! Much appreciated. :)

Comment: @Monomeeth Thank you for your tips, it is indeed that I did not consider carefully enough.

Answer (score -2):

Try holding the home button and the power button for 10 seconds.  If it worked, the Apple logo will appear, then it should turn on.